# Reversing and returning a string

Tags: python

I am trying to write a function that takes a string and reverses the words in that string, and then returns the string. I have written this code but when I execute it nothing happens. A blank appears.

```
def reverse(tex):
new_w = " "
for i in range(0, len(tex)):
    new_w += text[len(tex) - 1 - i]
return new_w
```

Comment: The code should also `print` the result.

Answer (score 0):

```
>> name = "pawan"
>> name[::-1]
>> "nawap"
```

This is better, isn't it?

This is called slicing.

Here's the syntax for slicing:

```
[ first char to include : first char to exclude : step ]
```

**EDIT**: I suggest you take a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation).